# Анимация прогресс бара не работает

Tags: android, flutter, material-design, кроссплатформенность

Использовал пример из [документации](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html), но обновления значения нет (только если изменять размеры окна и скрывать/показывать всплывающее меню).
Как исправить?

[GIF Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c62C.jpg) | [Source Code](https://github.com/rustzz/passwd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было сделать виджет не stateless, а stateful. Моя вина, не увидел

[Пример](https://github.com/rustzz/passwd/commit/0cb007278b0634722abac136b2b5f2778c950962)